# Dynamically configuring subdomains based on folder structure using Apache's VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

What I want to do is have dynamically created virtualhosts based on a username and subfolder, for example if I were to create the following folder:

```
/home/USER/www/PROJECT_FOLDER
```

The following domain will be mapped to the previous folder as its webroot

```
http://PROJECT_FOLDER.USER.domain.com
```

Aside from creating a script that checks for new folders, creating the matching VirtualHost in the Apache configuration, and restarting HTTPD, is there a config-friendly method of accomplishing this?

-- EDIT --
Thank you @kashani for suggesting mod_vhost_alias. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into mod_vhost_alias. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

The config in your case should look like this, though I haven't tested it.

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/www/%1
```

and for logging

```
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" dynamic_vhosts
CustomLog logs/access_log dynamic_vhosts
```

That'll put the vhost the request came into at the front of each log entry. You can adjust the rest of the setting to match what you need. If %V doesn't work, try %v. I don't believe there is a way to split out into separate log files at least with the standard Apache mod_log.

Comment: Thanks @kashani! After working with mod_vhost_alias for a while, that seemed to do the trick! My only concern now is if the project_folder directory has capital letters in it the apache usually translates http://EXAMPLE.username.domain.com as "example.username.domain.com" when in fact the directory may be "/home/username/www/EXAMPLE"

Comment: I can't think of a way to solve that one, but glad to hear mod_vhost_alias worked out for you.

Comment: One more semi-related question. Is there any way to also have virtual mapping of error and access logs using mod_vhost_alias?

Comment: put the logging in the answer for better formating.

Comment: @Workman, mod_speling might help with the case sensitivity of the folders. But I've never used it in conjunction with mod_vhost_alias: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html

Answer (score 0):

With "ServerAlias *.example.com" and the Virtual User Hosts RewriteRule example, I believe you can easily setup apache to do what you wish

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#uservhosts

Comment: Can you do this with local hostnames as well? 

Such as PROJECT_FOLDER.USER.dev (where 'dev' is the name of the machine)?